# PHP binding values

Tags: php, pdo, bindvalue

I'm having problem binding multiple values. I've experimented with one value and it works fine. is there something I missed?

when I run the Query it gives me an error:
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\Media\admin\dashboard\classes\DB.php on line 35

```
private function runQuery($sql, $bind_value = array()) {
    $this->_error = false;
    if($ms = $this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $this->_query->bindValue($x, $bind_values);
        if($this->_query->execute()) { //**ERROR FOUND HERE**
            echo 'ok';
        }
        die();
    }
}

public function get($column, $table, $where = array()) {
    if($where) {
        if(count($where) === 3) {
            $operators = array(
                '=',
                '<',
                '>',
                '>=',
                '<='
            );

            $field      = $where[0];
            $operator   = $where[1];
            $value      = $where[2];

            $bind_value = array(
                $column,
                $table,
                $field,
                $operator,
                $value,
            );
            if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
                $sql = "SELECT ? ? WHERE ? ? ?";
                return $this->runQuery($sql, $bind_value);
            }
        } else {
            echo 'problem';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You violated here almost every rule of OOP. there shouldn't be variables like _query in your class.

What you really need is just these five lines:

```
public function runQuery($sql, $bind_value = array()) {
    $stmt = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($bind_value);
    return $stmt;
}
```

which have to *return* a statement, not set it as a class variable.

get() function is also useless and wrong and you better avoid it. If you really want a function to automate select queries, you have to look at the existing query builders, like AuraSQL.